# Meaning of read and syscall with arguments

Tags: c, system-calls

I'm playing with strace and ltrace tools to get information about a program which contains a prompt for a user entry.

With strace, after the read from the prompt is called, there is an openat of a specific file in readOnly:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "file", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "22d72c", 6)                    = 6
```

I know that the second argument for read is supposed to be a buffer and that read starts at the buffer, but what exatly does it mean here? Does it means it starts at the 22d72c bit? or is 22d72c a key and it reads it's value?

As for syscall, I'm getting that when I use ltrace, after a scanf for the prompt and a
fopen to open the file, it returns similar syscall such as:

```
syscall(0, 3, 0x56127f5c96c0, 6)
```

What is the meaning of syscall third argument here? (0x56127f5c96c0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `"22d72c"` are the *6 characters* that `read` read from your file... just check the beginning of `file`.

Indeed if you read from `STDIN_FILENO` using read (or for example use `fgets`; strace will output

```
read(0,
```

and *stop* there waiting for the read to complete so that it can print out the characters read!

---

As for

```
syscall(0, 3, 0x56127f5c96c0, 6)
```

that output is from a program that doesn't know how to *decode* the system call parameters for system call 0 (`read`), so it just displays some sensible value - all small numbers in decimal. `0x56127f5c96c0` is the pointer to the first character of the buffer you're `read`ing into.

Answer (score 2):

`0x56127f5c96c0` is the pointer passed to `read`. It's not very useful to you is it? `strace` was nice enough to decode the system call, notice that's a pointer argument, and show you what it points to instead.

Comment: (Antti Haapala added this stuff into his own answer after I answered, within the 5 minute window so it looks older but it isn't)

Comment: True, benefits of *fgitw*, though it wasn't plagiarism and I was going to write it - I just did the mid-save *just to get* my "Firts pots!!!" effect.